# Without duplication, count number of people entering each day

Tags: python, excel, vba, pivot-table

I am working with a worksheet as below:

```
Date/Time      Badge       Name
10/31/2013    
8:01:02 AM     131078      YEO, Nita
8:03:17 AM     415416      PEH, Wei
10/30/2013    
8:11:02 AM     131098      LEE, Alice
8:53:17 AM     215416      EG, shi
...
```

1. I want to count the number of people entered without dupication in one day. Just are the date, not the exact time. Each person has a unique Badge number.
2. After that, I have another worksheet with all the empoyees` Badge number. I want to compare the peoople entered with this sheet to exclude the visitors, i.e. the people inside both sheets remain. Then count how many.

To sum up, in one month, count number of empoyees but not visitors entered in each day. and plot the number against date.

How this can be done using excel, pivot table or VBA?

Comment: One recommendation: You currently have the date as its own row, and only the time in the other rows. This problem gets much easier if you simply use the full date and time in each row, and eliminate the date rows.

Comment: Agreed, if you have every row contain all the necessary information on its own, a pure Excel solution would be simple too.

Comment: There are two helpful answers below which you seem to have forgotten to respond to. I personally think it is not acceptable to receive help and then not express some gratitude in some way, e.g. by upvoting, accepting or commenting. Given that your other two questions requested "urgent" treatment, I wonder therefore whether your expectations of a volunteer community need revising somewhat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, add a column on the extreme left and, assuming ‘Date/Time’ is then in B1, in A2 enter `=IF(ISBLANK(C2),B2,A1)` and copy down to suit. Copy ColumnA and Paste Special, Values over the top. Filter ColumnC for (Blanks) and delete the selected rows. Add `Date` in A1. Your data layout should now be more-or-less as @Brett recommended.

---

Use a lookup function to add to each row indication of whether or not Visitor.

A PivotTable constructed as indicated from the source data as on the left in the image will show the number of unique badge visits by day:

[image: SO19764305 example]

Filter to select only `n` in the Report Filter field and you have the equivalent for employees only.

For monthly figures use the Group (on the Quick Menu), By, Months facility.

For charting, remove Badge from Row Labels and Insert a suitable chart.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# collect all visitors in a dictionary where the key is the date, and
# the value is a set of badge numbers
visitorsPerDay = defaultdict(set)

# store the last read date value
currentDate = None

with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        # if the line is 10 characters long, it’s a date line
        if len(line.strip()) == 10:
            # store the date value
            currentDate = line.strip()
        elif currentDate:
            # extract the badge number; if the file is tab
            # separated, even better: split by \t
            time, badge, _ = (part.strip() for part in line.split('   ', 2))

            # add the badge number to the set within the dictionary
            visitorsPerDay[currentDate].add(badge)

# now for every date, count the number of (unique) visitors
for date, visitors in visitorsPerDay.items():
    print(date, len(visitors))
```